# Is there 404 hits list in database?

Tags: database, magento2.3, 404

I was wondering does magento store somewhere 404 requests by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Magento does NOT save any 404 requests anywhere.**

If you want to track 404 requests, check [404 Error Logger](https://marketplace.magento.com/raveinfosys-tracknoroute.html) extension and it's FREE.